# EFQ SQL error when using filedCondition on two different taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, database

I'm using the below code to select a 'store' content type which has two taxonomy fields: category and brand.

```
$queryStore = new EntityFieldQuery();
$queryStore->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle','store', '=')
  ->propertyCondition('status', NODE_PUBLISHED)
  ->fieldCondition('field_city','tid', $city_id, '=')      
  ->addMetaData('account', user_load(1))
  ->execute;  

 if ($_GET['category'] != 'Choose a category'){
   $queryStore->fieldCondition('field_category','tid', $category_id, '=');
 }
 if ($_GET['brand'] != '') {
   $queryStore->fieldCondition('field_brand','tid', $brand_id, '=');
 }
```

However when I choose a brand like Chanel and a category like Food (naturally such node doesn't exist since Chanel doesn't do food), I get the following error:

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')) AND (field_data_field_city0.deleted...

I'm using Drupal 7.
Is there a way to avoid such error? 
I appreciate any help given

Thanks

Comment: Sanitize those $_GETs and check that they are an integer before passing them in.

Answer (score 0):

If you check your error you will notice that your query is trying to look for a column named field_data_field_city0.deleted... , it appends a 0 to it. This problem occurs because the type of value you choose for that column in field query is not correct.

Can you check an confirm if field_city is a taxonomy type of field. If you can access your DB check the table field_data_field_city and check what is the name of last column.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, I can confirm that city is a taxonomy type field, term reference. I'll check what you suggested and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I figured it out, it was related to another function I wrote